# Django-inplaceedit VariableDoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-inplaceedit

I have a simple template

```
{% extends "layout/index.html" %}
{% load inplace_edit %}

{% inplace_edit  "category.name" %}

{% for item in items %}
    {% inplace_edit  "item.title" %}
{% endfor %}
```

my views.py

```
def category(request, category_id): 
    return render_to_response("items/category.html",
                              {
                              'category':category,
                              'items':Item.objects.filter(site__categories__id=category_id).filter(publicated=True).order_by('-created'),
                              },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I try to edit category all works fine

```
{% inplace_edit  "category.name" %}
```

But, when I try to insert editor in items in loop I have an error:

> VariableDoesNotExist at /category/1/ Failed lookup for key [ "item] in
>   u"[{'False': False, 'None': None, 'True': True}, {}, {}]"

Comment: Hi Treon, I've just started using inplaceedit and encountered the same problem. did you ever find the solution? Thank you